# Ms.DynamicsCRM2011 + Work Flow +how to know Lead converted to what?

Tags: workflow-foundation, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have created workflow for alerting to admin, when new lead/opportunity/account will created/Updated/Converted/Qualified,CRM2011 will send email notification to admins.email router configured.

My question is

When we click Qualify button to convert lead in ms.crm2011 online ,then in converted event workflow will run and it can send email. but how can we know here lead is converted to which entities? means which options are selected during convertion, (account,contact,opportunity)? so we can give specific message to admin that these lead is onverted to ....opportunity and account etc..,

can any one suggest the way for this.

thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

You Should make the workflow on the entities into which lead has been converted,
so when the new opportunity or contact or account will be there in crm then work flow will run and send the e-mail regardind the lead.
NOTE: In work flow creation use the condition that "source is lead" .